# How to add to object new parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to add to object new parameters in foreach loop in JS?

```
const data = [big data];
data.forEach(async e => {
    Object.assign(e, {newData: 'string'};
    console.log(e); //added new parameter
})
console.log(data); //not added new parameter, why?
```

i need to add new parameter to object in foreach loop, when i console.log after all Object.assign i see that i have new parameter, but when iterate is done and I console.log my array of object I see that no one of the object have new parameter, can somebody tell me why?

Comment: That should work. If it doesn't, please make a [MCVE] in a runnable Stack Snippet so we can see the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your syntax (missed comma, quotes around string etc). Check solution below

UPD: if you need to add to object, then define object (not string) in array

```js
const data = [{"big":true}, {"data":true}];
data.forEach(e => {
    Object.assign(e, {newData: 'string'});
    console.log(e); //added new parameter
});
console.log(data); //not added new parameter, why?
```

UPD: you added `async` in your question in forEach loop... Unfortunately async is bad idea for `forEach` function, instead use old good `for`

```js
// Timeout
const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

// Run in async function!
(async ()=> {
  // Your array of objects
  const data = [{"big":true}, {"data":true}];
  // Loop
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const e = data[i];
      // Sleep 1 sec
      await timeout(1000);
      // Assign
      Object.assign(e, {newData: 'string'});
      // Debug
      console.log(e);
  }
  // Result will be displayed after all
  // awaits from loop is completed
  console.log("result", data);
})();
```

Comment: i see that not add you new property

Comment: Check updated answer. Can't understand clearly what result do you want to get?

Comment: you don;t understand the problem, I must add to one object new property

Comment: well that's exactly what happening in my example - you have array with 2 objects, you iterate them in `forEach` loop and assign to each object new property `newData`

Comment: but i have `async` in my foreach loop before `e`, i think that this is a problem

Comment: @ProPlemionaGamer That is essential information that should exist in your question. Please show your *actual* code in the question, copied from your actual project, not psudeocode.

Comment: I can't, but i think that all code what is in main post should help us

Comment: @ProPlemionaGamer check my update to post - don't use async with forEach, use `for` instead

Answer (score -1):

`Object.assign()` returns the newly created object.

if you are trying to return an array of new objects use the map function.

```
const data = ["big", "data"];
let newArray = data.map(e => {
    return Object.assign({}, {newData: e});
});
console.log(newArray);
```

update: your question is unclear. If you need one object from the array:

```
let result = {}
const data = ["big", "data"];
data.forEach(e => {
    result[e] = 'string';
});
console.log(result);
```